# Hide Column if Total in the footer of that column is 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table called `mtable` and it has 28 columns and also I have a checkbox my questions is this.

How to hide columns if the total of that columns is zero(0)? You know, the `footerCallback` this is my sample code for testing

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
  var expgltable =  $('#mtable').DataTable()
  var column = expgltable.column(2);
  var api = this.api();

  var test = $(api.column(28).footer());
  if (test == 0) {
    column.visible( ! column.visible() );
  } 
});
```

trying yo hide the column 28 if it is zero total in footer but seems not working for me.

My target here is This

```
/* On checkbox event */
if (checkbox is checked) {
  /* Hide all columns that has 0 total on footers */
} else {
  /* Put it all back */
}
```

TYSM

Answer (score 0):

please see if this helps

```
$('#mtable').DataTable( {
    footerCallback: function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {        
        var sumofSalary = api
            .column(28)
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            } );
    });
});

if(sumofSalary == 0) {
    // logic for column hide;
}
```